# Applying for Netherlands Working Holiday Scheme whilst in the Netherlands

Tags: visas, netherlands, australian-citizens

I am an Australian and eligible for the [Netherlands Working Holiday Scheme](http://australia.nlembassy.org/services/visa/working-holiday-scheme%5B2%5D.html). However, I am already in the Netherlands (my partner has a job here so I came over with him at short notice).

Can anyone help me with my options? I know that I can apply from the UK, but it seems as though I need to prove I have been a UK resident for at least 3 months. Can I just fly over and apply and then come back to the Netherlands?

Comment: Based on reading the page you will have to be in Australia to receive it.

Answer (score 2):

Well according to [this link](http://australia.nlembassy.org/services/visa/working-holiday-scheme%5B2%5D.html) the normal procedure is to go to the Netherlands and the apply there to the IND there within 3 days. I'm not sure if I've missed something you need to do before that, I would have expected you to have to get something for your home country (as you imply) but I've looked around the official NL sites and can't see anything that says that -- if you have a link or other info please comment or update the question.

If you've been in the Netherlands for more than 3 days already you might need to go to a non Schengen country (i.e. the UK) and then re-enter the Netherlands and approach the IND. However it's worth phoning the IND, explaining the situation, and asking if you need to.

Basically I'd definitely contact the IND, contact details [here](http://www.ind.nl/en/Contact/Pages/default.aspx).

Comment: Register in 3 days or go in-and-out and register within 3 days. It's illegal stay if you don't register but border patrol doesn't complain when you're already leaving (it's a stupid rule and they know it).